Какие JS-библиотеки можно использ. для такой анимации?
Сайт: https://polarads.com
Меня интересует эффект "падения" картинок и переключения слайдов
Я посмотрел какие JS-библиотеки там используются - Scrollax.js и Delighter.js, какие-то мало-известные. Но я так и не смог понять, какая библиотека там отвечает за какой эффект.
Буду рад, если подскажете что каждая конкретно делают этом сайте, и можно ли их обе заменить на Gsap?
*По началу анимация мне показалась довольно сложной, но я думаю можно сделать такую же, используя только GSAP и Swiper-Slider, как думаете?

5 кадров в секунду. Пожалуйста, не надо делать такие анимации вообще

это не RDR 2 на ультрах, тут fps не важны
очень конечно по делу комментарий был
